# hwclock synchronization failed

Tags: date-time, gnome3, systemctl, debian-bullseye

After suspend/resume the system time is wrong ([Set system time after Suspend](https://superuser.com/questions/1726050/set-system-time-after-suspend)) Not giving up. It was alluded (in answers) that it might be connected with the CMOS clock malfunction. Tried to investigate and found that hwclock:

```
$ sudo hwclock --verbose
hwclock from util-linux 2.36.1
System Time: 1658943089.883117
Trying to open: /dev/rtc0
Using the rtc interface to the clock.
Assuming hardware clock is kept in UTC time.
Waiting for clock tick...
ioctl(4, RTC_UIE_ON, 0): Invalid argument
Waiting in loop for time from /dev/rtc0 to change
hwclock: ioctl(RTC_RD_TIME) to /dev/rtc0 to read the time failed: Invalid argument
...synchronization failed
```

How can I get hwclock working ?

```
Using
AMD A6-5400K APU with Radeon Version E7792AMS V2.2.
Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
GNOME Version 3.38.5
```

Comment: Have you checked the clock battery?

Comment: After power off when entered CMOS, the clock is ticking but the date/time is wrong.